# Test function within a function with Jest?

Tags: jestjs

I'm testing a Redux Action Creator with Jest

This is the action creator:

```js
const addDiscount = ({ code }) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { id } = getState().token;

  return dispatch({
    apiCall: discount.put({
      body: {
        code
      },
      id
    }),
    types: ADD_DISCOUNT.triplet
  });
};
```

And this is my test:

```js
const apiCallMock = jest.fn();
const dispatch = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    apiCall: apiCallMock
  };
});
const customerOrderId = 'customer-order-id';
const getState = jest.fn(() => ({
  token: {
    customerOrderId
  }
}));

const res = addDiscount({ code: 'abc123' })(dispatch, getState);

console.log(res);
console.log(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]);
console.log(apiCallMock.mock);
```

If I try `console.log(res)` the result is `undefined`.

`console.log(dispatch.mock.calls[0][0]);` shows me types but apiCall is a function that hasn't been run.

`console.log(apiCallMock.mock);` appears to have not been run

Comment: Nothing calls the apiCallMock, your mock dispatch returns an object which has the function as a property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution only using `jest`:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { discount } from './discount';

export const ADD_DISCOUNT = {
  triplet: 'triplet'
};

export const addDiscount = ({ code }) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { id } = getState().token;

  return dispatch({
    apiCall: discount.put({ body: { code }, id }),
    types: ADD_DISCOUNT.triplet
  });
};
```

`discount.ts`:

```js
export const discount = {
  put(obj) {
    return obj;
  }
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { addDiscount, ADD_DISCOUNT } from './';
import { discount } from './discount';

describe('addDiscount', () => {
  test('should ', () => {
    const customerOrderId = 'customer-order-id';
    const mDispatch = jest.fn();
    const mGetState = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ token: { id: customerOrderId } });
    const putSpy = jest.spyOn(discount, 'put');
    addDiscount({ code: 'abc123' })(mDispatch, mGetState);
    expect(mGetState).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mDispatch).toBeCalledWith({
      apiCall: { body: { code: 'abc123' }, id: customerOrderId },
      types: ADD_DISCOUNT.triplet
    });
    expect(putSpy).toBeCalledWith({ body: { code: 'abc123' }, id: customerOrderId });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/55936794/index.spec.ts (9.651s)
  addDiscount
    ✓ should dispatch action correctly (7ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 discount.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.79s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/55936794